# Use Case point estimation technique - TOP DOWN

Tags: estimation

Is [User Case Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_Case_Points) estimation technique "[TOP-DOWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design)" approach?

Comment: What is unclear about it, that you cannot answer that question yourself? This is not a trivia site, where we answer "yes" or "no". If we don't know what you found unclear, we don't know what to explain to you.

Answer (score 2):

UCP estimation is not necessarily a TOP DOWN approach, because use cases are not always detailed from top to bottom. In fact, use cases are related to UML and RUP, trying to document the customer's requirements in technical and natural language. So the answer is no, it can be, but not always.

Check this: http://modelmeld.com/Usecases-topdownandbottomup.html